# Is there any possibility to get VMWARE HOST computer name from GUEST workstation without changing things on HOST?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

Let's suppose I have VMWARE workstation (guesting Windows and hosted by Windows). 
Is there any possible way to receive host name of hosting machine?
And without changing things on host machine like in [this link](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/131180).

Comment: http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/01/how-to-extract-host-information-from.html

Answer (score 9):

I do this by passing a string from host to guest via machine.id.  It does require making a change on the host (in every VM's .vmx file, too), and it doesn't automatically discover the host's hostname, but it works.  On the host, with the VM in question powered down, edit the .vmx file for the VM.  Find or add a line that looks like:

```
machine.id = "<string>"
```

Set `<string>` equal to some identifying string that will tell you the name of the server.  This could be the hostname, or it could be a shortened version of it, or even some unintelligible code if you prefer, as long as you know what it means.  If, however, the .vmx file has a line that sets

```
isolation.tools.machine.id.get.disable = TRUE
```

passing a string won't work, so if this line is present you might want to either remove/comment it or set the value to `FALSE`.

On the guest OS, if you have VMware Tools installed, you can then do this (for Linux guests):

```
vmware-guestd --cmd 'machine.id.get'
```

or (for Windows guests, which I haven't tried):

```
VMwareService --cmd machine.id.get
```

Comment: Without having tried this thoroughly: The "new" command seems to be `vmware-rpctool 'machine.id.get'` under Linux

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, however if anyone is still interested "thomas lee"'s answer above works on recent version of **VMWare workstation** and **VMWare fusion**.  The new command to retrieve the value is

```
rpctool machine.id.get
```

Using this in deploying managed VMs for Fusion so that the machine name is auto set at first boot.  Thanks Thomas.....

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to install [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/) on your guest operating system, you can access some ESX host information by looking up the VM that your script is running on:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server <myvcenterserver>

$myVM = Get-VM -Name $(dir env:COMPUTERNAME).Value

$myVM.Host.Name
```

Note: This assumes your guest has the same hostname as the VM name in vCenter.

For Linux guests (the OP stated Windows) I use the [pyVmomi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvmomi) Python module to perform a similar lookup.

Answer (score 2):

In principle - no.

However, it is possible that there may exist (or will exist) certain vulnerabilities that allow a malicious guest OS to bypass the VM sandbox. For instance, read up on the [Blue Pill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_(malware)). You can also read more details on the researcher's own blog, [Invisible Things by Joanna Rutkowska](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2006/06/introducing-blue-pill.html).
Of course, these are just proof of concept, but any security implemented in software is subject to software bugs...

Answer (score 2):

I think there are probably a number of ways to do this, and can think of two off the bat:
One would be to install ViX in the guest, connect to the host without specifying the hostname, (Google "ViX reference" then see "common tasks") then use `Vix_CopyFileFromHostToGuest()` to copy the file `/etc/vmware/esx.conf`.
Another would be to create some sort of network connection from the guest to the host (I used `ssh` but if you don't know the hostname or IP you could still do the ViX connection thing as above and dispatch a job that takes a while) and then say `netstat -a` in the guest.  The `netstat` output will contain the hostname, if it is resolvable.

Comment: It's probably better to provide a link rather than assuming people will end up the same place you had in mind after Googling.

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively two computers on a network.  If you use one of the private network/NAT style set-ups for the virtual NICs, then the host has a fairly predictable IP address, so you could then use any of the many remote admin approaches to ask it just like you would any other.

If there is only the one guest OS, then just trying every IP address with the same leading 24 bits as the guest's IP address would save baking in a guess at an address.

Answer (score 1):

In vSphere

1. Click your host
2. Click Configuration Tab
3. In Software Section Click DNS and Routing

[image: VMware|vCenter|vSphere Host Configuration]

Comment: I realize that this isn't from the guest OS but if your trying to get that information from the a VM Guest Host then your not an admin. You should have access to vSphere via vCenter.